# Where is WPF DataGrid DataBindingComplete event?

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid

I need to take some action (e.g. make some cells readonly based on some other cells) after data biinding is completed. In WinForm DataGridView, I used to do it in DataBindingComplete event. However, I couldn't find such an event in WPF DataGrid. What else can I use?

Comment: What do you want to perform upon the completion of data binding?

Comment: As I stated in question, I want to make some cells disabled based on the value of the other column on the same row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I figured out: DataContextChanged event is the right event to use. The only problem is that the datagrid is not quite ready to be consumed in my code inside this event. However, it works fine if I use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => DoSomethingWithGrid()));
```

Can anybody explain why this is necessary?

Actually, when dealing with WPF DataGrid, I had to use Dispatcher in quite a few cases in order to make it work. Why?

Comment: This event may fire before databinding is complete. See the important remark at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to color my rows depending on their property values, and I tried a lot of events (`DataGrid.Initialized`, `DataContextChanged`, `AddingNewItem`, `RowLoaded` etc.) along with the `BeginInvoke` thing, but nothing worked. Then i found:

### `Loaded`

This event did the trick, as it allowed me to iterate through my rows and color them as I wanted.

```
private void SubjectsList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => ColorMyRows()));
}
```

The `CollorMyRows` looks pretty similar to tihs:

```
private void ColorMyRows()
{
    DataGridRow row = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < SubjectsList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        // get one row
        row = SubjectsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
        if (myConditionIsFulfilled)
        {
            row.Background = Brushes.PaleGoldenrod; // black'n gold baby
            row.ToolTip = "This item fulfills the condition.";
        }
        else
        {
            row.Background = Brushes.PaleGreen;
            row.ToolTip = "This item does not.";
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: If You have an `ObservableCollection` bound to a `DataGrid`, the index in the loop (index of a `DataGrid`'s row) will correspond to the index in the collection :)

Answer (score 1):

DataContextChanged.

Comment: It is strange. Somehow DataContextChanged event doesn't work for me. What I want to do is to disable some cells in a column based on the value of another column in the same row. The same code works if I put it in a cell click event, but it doesn't work in DataContextChanged event. I have the feeling that the DataGrid is not ready yet when this event is fired, that's why my update is not taking effect - just a guess. Any clue?

Comment: I think you can rather easily do this with an IValueConverter and a style setting. I could write a sample for this, but it would take a few days.

Comment: I'm not sure if styles will solve all my problems in this respect. In my app in WinForm (which I'm trying to convert to WPF), a lot of DataGridView is used. In DataBindingComplete event, we do a bit more than just setup up visual effect. But styles will definitely save me some trouble.

Comment: @Chris: I'm very interested in your suggestion of using IValueConverter and Style. Could you please provide me some sample code? Thanks!

Comment: @miliu It appears that IsReadOnly cannot be set on an individual Cell basis with styles and IValueConverters. Only at the Column level. So, unfortunately, I can't provide any code that helps with your specific case. Sorry miliu. I was hoping it would work.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks anyway. I hope microsoft will add the cell-level readonly read/write property in the next release. In the meantime, I guess I have to use WPF toolkit datagrid so that I can change the source code directly.

Comment: This event may fire before databinding is complete. See the important remark at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged.aspx

Answer (score 1):

May be you are using threads and datagrid is not thread-safe as all UI components.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind cells readonly property to a property that changes when other properties of the model changes.
I was thinking exactly like you while ago, but I started to think more in the model more than the view I am not interested in DataGrid but the list that is bounded to, you can do the same
I used it before in a similar situation

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                RaisePropertyChanged("Visibilty");
            }
        }
public Visibility Visibilty
        {
            get
            {
                return IsChecked ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
}
```

it was a checkbox in datagrid bound to IsChecked Property and other cells bounded to visibility and it worked for me.
hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a BackgroundWorker and try to fill your GridView in the DoWork event and write your code in the RunWorkerCompleted event