# How to know when binding is completed?

Tags: wpf, events, binding, itemssource

When I set the .ItemSource() property on a DataGrid to a Collection, the call returns fast, but the actual binding happens afterwards. Since I want to display a waiting cursor, I need to detect when the actual binding has finished. Is there any event for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything based on ItemsControl uses an ItemContainerGenerator to generate its items in the background. You can access the ItemContainerGenerator property of the DataGrid and hook up the StatusChanged event to determine when it's done. If you're using virtualization and scroll, this will fire again so you need to handle that if necessary in your case.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. For some reason it fires multiple times when I set the ItemsSource (without any scrolling), is that normal when you use virtulization?

Comment: Could you be raising a property changed event or collection changed event on your collection multiple times when you set it? Like maybe you're setting the ItemsSource property then adding items to it? Either that or maybe it's something about how DataGrid works, I haven't used it that much

Comment: No it's a read-only collection which never changes. It has a .Status property which changes from Generating to Generated, so it's logical that it fires two times, but I see it firing 6 times (status: 2,1,2,1,2,1), I will see if the stack-trace can shed some light into this.

Answer (score 0):

I waited for my `DataGrid`'s `Loaded` event to fire, and I did a `BeginInvoke`, like this:

```
private void SubjectsList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => ColorMyRows()));
}
```

More details available in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44464630/2101117

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to hook into OnPropertyChanged event in your Window or User Control. This event is fired every time a property is updated. Then check for the actual property you wish to observe and take action.

```
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ("YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME".Equals(e.Property.ToString()))
        {
            // Take action
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
```